# How do I convince capybara to click on the <details> element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I have markup that looks like:

```
<div class="alert">
  <details>
    <summary>
      This question is currently shared across
      <strong>2 surveys.</strong>
      Changes made to this question will be applied everywhere it's shared.
    </summary>
    <ol>
      <li><a href="/admin/surveys/1/questions"><i class="icon-share"></i> Test Survey <span class="badge">source</span></a>   </li>
      <li><a href="/admin/surveys/2/questions"><i class="icon-share"></i> New Survey 2014-11-11 22:14:47</a></li>
    </ol>
  </details>
</div>
```

How do I convince capybara to click on the `<details>`?

Answer (score 3):

Try with `find('.alert > details').click`

With the above Capybara will try to find a details element within a div.alert (Capybara uses CSS as the default selector). You can define your cucumber step as the following:

```
When(/^I click on details inside an alert$/) do
  find('.alert > details').click
end
```

Comment: Care to explain your solution?

Comment: @EvertonAgner I thought the solution was quite simple and didn't need an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution is a bizarre approach, but it can help anyway.

As you will need JQuery, you must change your driver:

Setup:

1. Gemfile:
   gem 'capybara-webkit'
2. (system) I'm in Debian, so I must:
   apt-get install qt4-qmake qt4-default
3. in your spec file, after the require:
   Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
4. In the context/describe:
   context '...', :js => true do

Now, that's the solution:

```
visit some_path
page.execute_script("$('#my_detail').attr('open', '')")
expect(find('#my_detail')['open']).to eq('open')
```

The JQuery $('#my_detail').attr('open', '') match id = my_detail and add the attribute 'open' with value blank (it's what happen when you click).

Then, to test if it's really open, I did the expect.

This test is green. If you comment the 'page.execute', the test will fail.